# Does there exist a $(m,n)\in\mathbb N$ such that $m^3-2^n=3$?

Tags: number-theory

> **Question** : Does there exist a $(m,n)\in\mathbb N$ such that $m^3-2^n=3$?

I know that there is no $(m,n)\in\mathbb N$ such that $m^3-2^n=1$ and that there is no $(m,n)\in\mathbb N$ such that $m^3-2^n=2$. However, I don't have any good idea to solve the question. I'm afraid that it may be a famous *unsolved* question. I would like to know any relevant references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gerry Myerson, I found [this](http://oeis.org/A081121). Hence, we can see that the answer to the question is **No**.

Comment: Yes, this is also mentioned in the literature on Pillai's equation (for some cases where "at most one solutions" means no solution).

Answer (score 3):

This is Pillai's equation $a^x-b^y=c$, which has been solved for many cases. For a survey on the results see the papers of [Michael A.  Bennett](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper26.pdf), [Bugeaud](http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2006/12-12v.pdf) and others. Theorem $1.1$ in Bennetts paper [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper19.pdf) states:

**Theorem**: If $a, b$ and $c$ are nonzero integers with $a,b \ge 2$, then Pillai's equation $a^x-b^y=c$ has at most two solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$.

Actually, for $1\le c\le 100$, Theorem $1.5$ says that we have at most $1$ solution in our case (the case $m=1$ is trivial here).

Comment: so based on that theorem, a and b must be greater or equal to 2, so that the equation would have two solutions max.. so x must be one positive integer..and the same goes for y. right?

Comment: @usukidoll: By Theorem $1.5$ there is at most one solution $(x,y)$ in positive integers for $m^x-2^y=3$, for $m\ge 2$. The case $m=1$ is trivial.

Comment: but what happens after I plug $m=1$? I can't leave it as $1^x-2^y=3$ and even if I find some numbers for x and y I would get a negative.

Comment: maybe since $m=1$, we can't satisfy the equation. Suppose $y=1$ and we have $ 1 = 2^1 +3$. Then $ 1 \neq 5$

Comment: @usukidoll: Not "maybe", but *certainly* the equation $1=2^y+3$ has *no* solution in positive integers. So the case $m=1$ is trivial.

Comment: ah right... sorry I'm new to proofs. It really depends on the definition and the problem. I can handle the easy ones but not the ones with multiple definitions being used. so did we disprove the theorem if we let $m=1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I'm happy to know the information. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is even, we have $$r^2=m^3-3$$ If $n$ is odd, we have $2r^2=m^3-3$, which leads (on multiplying by 8) to $$y^2=x^3-24$$ These are both instances of Mordell's equation, $$y^2=x^3-k$$ Solutions to Mordell's equation have been tabulated for many values of $k$, certainly for all $k\le100$, and I'm sure they can be found by searching the web for "Mordell equation".

Comment: I'm very happy to know the word. Very helpful. Thank you.