# Pillai equation solvability

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to learn an elementary method of solving Pillai equation.

The equation $a^x-b^y = c$ has at most two solutions for $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{Z} $, where $a$ and $b$ are greater than or equal to $2.$

please let me learn an elementary method to prove the cited above statement.

High regards

Comment: Not sure you will find an "elementary" method. Check http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf

Comment: @Macaviy! can you give some other method.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854066/does-there-exist-a-m-n-in-mathbb-n-such-that-m3-2n-3.