# Proof of Power of Twos and Threes

Tags: number-theory

Are $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$, and $(8,9)$ the only consecutive integers that are a power of two and a power of three? And if they are, how do I prove this?

Comment: 0 is not a power of 2. I'm not sure if it's true or how to prove it. My only thoughts are: Let $2^{k}+1=3^n$ or $2^k-1=3^n$. From some rearranging we get $1=3^n-2^k$ or $1=2^k-3^n$.

Comment: @PaulSundheim He seems to mean _consecutive integers such that one of them is a power of 2 and the other is a power of 3_

Comment: @Hippalectryon Thanks, I got that and deleted the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to add:**

Your question is fully answered in [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29928/767), which provides an elementary proof (first published in about 1320).

**Orginal answer:**

Yes, these are the only solutions. This follows from [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture), which is also called Mihăilescu's theorem since 2002, when it was proved by Preda Mihăilescu. It states that $8$ and $9$ are the only consecutive integers that are both perfect powers.

The proof is difficult. There might well exist more elementary proofs for your special case, but I am not aware of them.

Comment: Yes, this is also cited in the literature on Pillai's equation. Several "easy" cases are already solved, but the conjecture is still open in general.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^a-y^b=1$ with $x, a, y, b > 1$ has only one solution, namely $x = 3, a = 2, y = 2, b = 3$. This is Catalan's conjecture, solved by Mihăilescu - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture). More generally, there is Pillai's conjecture, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854066/does-there-exist-a-m-n-in-mathbb-n-such-that-m3-2n-3).